# Override .Net Resource file in Calling Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I have an asp.net 2.0 web application that is calling class library. A fairly common scenario to be sure.

The class library is making use of a number of resource files and a ResourceManager object to set localised strings. This works absolutely fine in most circumstances based on the user's browser settings.

However there are some circumstances under which I wish to overrride the resource string in the class library from within the web application.

Is this possible? if so how?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's nothing "out of the box" to allow you to do this.

On the other hand - you could always expose those strings you might wish to override in your class library as public properties, and initialize them inside your class library to your default strings from the resources, but since they're public properties, the calling web app could always override them and set new values.

Marc